# Attackers seem to have accessed my Chase online login information. How might this have happened?

Tags: passwords

I recently noticed a series of small deposits made via Chase’s mobile deposit feature. I didn’t deposit this money (there were five deposits, all under $20). My guess is that an attacker wanted to see if anyone was monitoring the account. I called Chase to freeze my account, and they’re “conducting an investigation” as well.

I’m not sure how this happened. My best guess is that it has something to do with a guest network in my apartment building that I sometimes connect to, and might have accidentally used to log into my Chase account. But Chase uses HTTPS, so shouldn’t that not matter? I doubt it’s malware on any of my devices — I use Ubuntu and iOS exclusively, and don’t install much third-party software on either. I don’t have an information security background, so I’m not sure about the situation. If that’s not it, how might this have happened? My password for Chase isn’t used for any of my other accounts. It’s probably not an excellent one, but it’s also not terrible. I’ve never told anyone the password. How might this have happened? Is there anything I can do to learn more about how it happened? What should I do to prevent this from occuring in the future?

Update: To any future readers, this turned out to be nothing malicious, just something stupid.

Answer (score 3):

**Contact your bank and file your complain.**

This can be a sign of "Refund scams".

The scammer will contact you as a fake bank officer, use a pre-crafted social engineering script to ask you to follow step to "return money" that does not belong to you.

Remember, if this is really a wrong deposit, the bank should reverse it WITHOUT your details or various personal authentication info.

[check this link for detail](https://www.nedbank.co.za/content/nedbank/desktop/gt/en/aboutus/legal/fraud-awareness/deposit-and-refunding-scams.html)

Answer (score -1):

This is more likely a MITM or rogue Wi-Fi AP that you connected to.  If you are not using a VPN before connecting to Chase and you are opening yourself up to capturing your credentials.

Comment: *"If you are not using a VPN before connecting to Chase and you are opening yourself up to capturing your credentials."* - interesting claim but can you prove it? As OP explicitly said: Chase uses HTTPS. So how could an attacker capture the credentials? Apart from that no credentials should be needed to make a deposit, the account number and name should be sufficient.